# Milliseconds missing when getting a DateTime value from Excel using .Net Interop

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com-interop

If I put a DateTime value into an Excel cell using `Range.set_value` through .Net COM Interop, and then retrieve the value of that same cell using `Range.get_value`, the Millisecond part of the value is not returned, though everything else is correct.

Is this a bug?

What is the workaround? I'm guessing that using the Value2 property instead might help. Has anybody else tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jon suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298458/milliseconds-missing-when-getting-a-datatime-value-from-excel-using-net-interop#298467), converting the DateTime to a double using DateTime.ToOADate (then back again using DateTime.FromOADate) works if you set the value using the Range.Value2 property.

The only trouble with this property is that, if you don't already know, it doesn't tell you that the cell is supposed to be treated as a DateTime. I guess to solve this, you'd need to use a two-pass approach: get cell values using Range.get_Value to determine their type, then, for any DateTime cells, get their values again using Range.Value2, then convert using DateTime.FromOADate.

Comment: that or you could check the number format of the cell. probably less expensive than using .Value followed by .Value2

Answer (score 4):

If you set a date/time with a millisecond value in Excel manually, does it maintain it? I don't know about the Excel internal object model, but it's conceivable that it just doesn't support milliseconds.

EDIT: Okay, now we know that the set fails (the get may also fail, of course)... you could try setting it as a double after converting it via [DateTime.ToOADate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx). I'm not saying I'm holding out *much* hope, but it's worth a try...

Comment: Jon,
 Yes it does maintain it, though you have to use custom cell formatting to display the millisecond component as well as the datetime part.

Comment: And having set it with .NET, if you save the worksheet can you see the results using the custom formatting? (That should indicate whether the problem is with the set or the get.)

Comment: Jon,
  Good thought: having set the value through .Net, the millisecond component doesn't actually show up, even with the custom formatting. Thus the problem starts with the set.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because of the issue described in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875526).

In which case, setting the Value2 property should work.